# How to start using Google Drive API on Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

### Background

I need to be able to backup and restore some files using Google Drive.

For this, I've found these websites:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/
- https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

### The problem

It is talked about various things that need to be done before using the code.

In the [**video**](https://youtu.be/_5HVm6FOUrk) they talk about SHA1 generation, yet in the github repository it is said :

> If you actually want to run this sample app (though it is mostly
>   provided so you can read the code), you will need to register an OAuth
>   2.0 client for the package com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo with your own debug keys and set any resource IDs to those that you
>   have access to. Resource ID definitions are on:
>
> com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
>   com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID

Thing is, I don't understand any of those things, as I never used them myself.

### The questions

1. About the SHA1 key generation, I've succeeded creating it, but what do I do with it?
2. How do I "register an OAuth 2.0 client..." ? What are the debug keys? How do I get them and what do I do with them?
3. What are the "resource IDs to those that you have access to" ? It seems in the sample that most of the sample Activities don't even use them. Are they maybe a kind of reference to real files/folders on Google Drive, that the app got permission to handle?
4. In the samples, it doesn't seem that they check for the availability of Google-Services. Is it not needed?
5. In the samples, all activities extend from a single activity that handles the connection. Is it ok to have a singleton that has a reference to the GoogleApiClient instance instead of re-connecting to it on each activity ?